# how to load popup first with label and button before application starts IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup

i want to display a popup view with labels and button it has to load before the application load the view controller means like if i install the application first it has to load the popup view after completing the popup view it has to open the application like that i want please tell is that possible how to do it.

This is the code i have already used to view the popup view in view did load.

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
         [super viewDidLoad];    
          UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"Please enter your name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
          UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
          alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
          alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter your name";
          [alert show];
          [alert release];  
       }
```

Please tell where i have to give this code to load before the application.

Thanks.

Comment: Take one extra view controller. In this write code only for AlertView.
After completion of this AlertView navigate to another ViewContoller Which is currently your first ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UINavigationController` in which your `rootViewController` will be the one with the `UIAlertView` and the `UITextField`.

In your `appDelegate`, inside `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
startScreenViewController *startScreenVC = [[startScreenViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:startScreenVC];

self.window.rootViewController = myNavigationController;
```

`startScreenViewController` is where you want to put the `UIAlertView` and the `UITextField`

Then, when the user inputs the info you can push a new `UIViewController` to your `UINavigationController` using this code inside `startScreenViewController`:

```
newViewController *newVC = [[newViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: sorry i'm not able to get u can please tell tittle clear so the i can able to understand

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make it easier to understand.

Comment: i want view only the popup once they open the application i dont want to view the view controller with the popup